# can't launch sparkR shell

Tags: windows, powershell, sparkr

Hi I'm following [this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio/) to start using sparkR

I downloaded and unzipped the spark package.
and I added java to system path,

but can't launch sparkR shell.

Here's thing in powershell:

```
PS D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin> java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
PS D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin> dir


    Directory: D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1099 beeline
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM            932 beeline.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1910 load-spark-env.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           2143 load-spark-env.sh
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           3459 pyspark
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1000 pyspark.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1486 pyspark2.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           2384 run-example
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1012 run-example.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           2682 run-example2.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           2858 spark-class
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1010 spark-class.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           2365 spark-class2.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           3026 spark-shell
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1008 spark-shell.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1528 spark-shell2.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1075 spark-sql
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1050 spark-submit
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1010 spark-submit.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1126 spark-submit2.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1049 sparkR
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM            998 sparkR.cmd
-a----        2/27/2016  12:02 AM           1010 sparkR2.cmd


PS D:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin> sparkR
sparkR : The term 'sparkR' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sparkR
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sparkR:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command sparkR was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell doe
s not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\sparkR". See "get-
help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Any help's appreciated. Thanks

---

update: the feedback in shell fixed it

```
Suggestion [3,General]: The command sparkR was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell doe
    s not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\sparkR". See "get-
    help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Comment: Did you read `Suggestion [3,General]:`? Did you try it? Did it works?

Comment: oh that fixed it. thanks @PetSerAl